# Editing the format of the output from print in Python

Tags: python

I have created a python script whose last four functions are print statements. I want the output of these statements to have a specific format. More specifically, I want them to be indented (using a tab), in bold, and, for the first one, also in italics.

This is my code so far:

```
print "Total", T
print "Rent", R
print "Utilities", U
print "Other", O
```

where T, R, U and O are numeric variables whose value was calculated throughout the script. Only `"Total", T` should be in italics in addition to being in bold and indented.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for make it bold, color, or having a tab (\t). I don't know about italics but will research

```
class color:
   PURPLE = '\033[95m'
   CYAN = '\033[96m'
   DARKCYAN = '\033[36m'
   BLUE = '\033[94m'
   GREEN = '\033[92m'
   YELLOW = '\033[93m'
   RED = '\033[91m'
   BOLD = '\033[1m'
   UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
   END = '\033[0m'

print(color.BOLD + color.RED + '\tTotal, T ' + color.END + color.END)
print(color.BOLD + color.RED + '\tRent, R' + color.END + color.END)
print(color.BOLD + color.RED + '\tUtilities, U' + color.END + color.END)
print(color.BOLD + color.RED + '\tOther, O' + color.END + color.END)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! How would this work? I mean, can I just copy-paste the print statements you typed or do I also need to enter the class color function? I'm sorry if this question is pretty basic, but I'm new to Python and I find it difficult...

Comment: @MeAll Yes you will need to include the `color` class.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of functionality isn't available through the print function, the output is text. You could potentially output HTML and render it somewhere as an alternative option.